# How to attach data a column to multiple columns in R

Tags: r, tidyr

Here is my data

```
df<-read.table (text="CBC   DSE BMD
1   S   BM
1   S   BM
1   S   BM
2   S   BM
2   S   BM
2   S   BM
3   S   BM
3   S   BM
3   S   BM
", header=TRUE)
```

I want to attach the data in the CBC column to the columns DSE and BMD

I can use

```
df %>% unite(DSE, DSE, CBC, sep="")
```

but this give me DSE, but when I use

```
df %>% unite(DSE, DSE, CBC, sep="")%>% unite(BMD, BMD, CBC, sep="")
```

I get error as I wouldn't get the following outcome

```
CBC DSE BMD
1   S1  BM1
1   S1  BM1
1   S1  BM1
2   S2  BM2
2   S2  BM2
2   S2  BM2
3   S3  BM3
3   S3  BM3
3   S3  BM3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, we could use `paste` or `str_c`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
    mutate(DSE = str_c(DSE, CBC), BMD = str_c(BMD, CBC))
```

-output

```
#  CBC DSE BMD
#1   1  S1 BM1
#2   1  S1 BM1
#3   1  S1 BM1
#4   2  S2 BM2
#5   2  S2 BM2
#6   2  S2 BM2
#7   3  S3 BM3
#8   3  S3 BM3
#9   3  S3 BM3
```

Or for multiple columns, can use `across`

```
df %>%
    mutate(across(c(DSE, BMD), ~ str_c(., CBC)))
```

---

Or if we intend to use `unite`, make sure to specify `remove = FALSE`.  By default, it is `remove = TRUE` and thus removes the input columns that are used in `unite`ing

```
df %>%
   unite(DSE, DSE, CBC, sep="", remove = FALSE) %>% 
   unite(BMD, BMD, CBC, sep="", remove = FALSE)
```

---

In the OP's code, error arises in the second `unite` as the column 'CBC' was removed in the previous `unite` because `remove = TRUE`

Answer (score 0):

A `data.table` option using `paste0`

```
setDT(df)[, c("DSE", "BMD") := lapply(.SD, function(x) paste0(x, CBC)), .SDcols = DSE:BMD]
```

gives

```
> df
   CBC DSE BMD
1:   1  S1 BM1
2:   1  S1 BM1
3:   1  S1 BM1
4:   2  S2 BM2
5:   2  S2 BM2
6:   2  S2 BM2
7:   3  S3 BM3
8:   3  S3 BM3
9:   3  S3 BM3
```

Answer (score 0):

In base R, you could do :

```
transform(df, DSE = paste0(DSE, CBC), BMD = paste0(BMD, CBC))

#  CBC DSE BMD
#1   1  S1 BM1
#2   1  S1 BM1
#3   1  S1 BM1
#4   2  S2 BM2
#5   2  S2 BM2
#6   2  S2 BM2
#7   3  S3 BM3
#8   3  S3 BM3
#9   3  S3 BM3
```